# Finding $k$-clique in a graph with running time of $|V|^{k-1}$

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, connectedness

This is a homework problem. Let's say I have a graph $G$, how can I find a $k$-clique (i.e. a complete graph with $k$ vertices) inside $G$? So far I can think of a naive solution where I check if each node in k is connected to other nodes, and the running time would be $|V|^k$. How can I reduced it by $|V|$ to $|V|^{k-1}$?

Comment: For $k = 3$ the best known complexity is $O(|V|^\omega)$, where $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication constant. While it is suspected that $\omega = 2$, which would imply an $O(|V|^{2+\epsilon})$ algorithm for every $\epsilon > 0$, this still falls short of your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nešetřil and Poljak](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/106381/CommentatMathUnivCarol_026-1985-2_22.pdf) give an algorithm running in time $O(n^{(\omega/3)k})$, for $k$ divisible by 3, which seems to be the state-of-the-art. This generalizes the well-known $O(n^\omega)$ algorithm for the case $k = 3$. Here $\omega$ is the matrix multiplication constant, currently known to be at most $2.373$, but conjectured to be $2$. See also [Vassilevska](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/combclique-ipl-g.pdf) (now Vassilevska-Williams), who gives an $o(n^k)$ algorithm which is space-efficient.